# MatPlotLib Graphs not showing

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, math, sympy

I am a begginer programmer and I'm trying to plot some graphs in python with math libraries and But I have some trouble.
I have to find some coordinates on the graph, sequentially, but the line simply doesnt appear on the screen, just the grid.

```
import math
import cmath
import numpy as np
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pi = 3.14159265


eps_r = 1.14
f = 27e6
Zo = 50
ZL = 50+75j

#começa a função
c = 299792458
vp = c / math.sqrt(eps_r)
Lambda = vp / f # comprimento de onda
Beta = 2 * pi / Lambda
d = np.arange(0, 1e-4, Lambda/4)  # Distância da Impedância na linhaà carga
Z_d = (Zo * ((ZL + 1j * Zo * math.tan(Beta * d)) / (Zo + 1j * ZL * math.tan(Beta * d)))) / Zo  # impendandia na linha a distancia d
Y_d = 1 / Z_d  # Y_d = Admitância

Re_Y = np.real(Y_d)
Im_Y = np.imag(Y_d)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(d, Re_Y)
ax.set(xlabel='d (m)', ylabel='Y(d) (1/Ohm)',
       title='Real da Admitância vs distância à carga (1/Ohm)')
ax.grid()
plt.show()

plt.plot(d, Im_Y)
plt.grid(True, which="both")
plt.title('Imaginário da Admitância vs distância à carga (1/Ohm)')
plt.xlabel('d (m)')
plt.ylabel('jY(d) (1/Ohm)')
plt.show()

Zin_Y = 1 / (-1j * Im_Y) * Zo
lstubv = (cmath.atan    (Zin_Y / (1j*Zo))  ) / Beta

lstubv = abs(lstubv)

plt.plot(Im_Y, lstubv)
plt.grid(True, which="both")
plt.title('módulo do Comprimento do STUB vs Y (1/Ohm)')
plt.xlabel('Yin (1/Ohm')
plt.ylabel('l (m))')
plt.show()

K = np.zeros(np.size(d))
for ct in range(1, 1, np.size(d, 2)):
    if .9999 <= Re_Y(ct) and Re_Y(ct) <= 1.0001:
        K = ct
k = np.mean(K)
if k == 0:
    k = np.find(abs(Re_Y - 1) < 1e-6)
k = np.mean(k)

x = (math.ceil(np.mean(k)))
dstub = x * 1e-4
print('Distância do stub à carga (m)'), print(dstub)
Imstub = Im_Y(x)
Zin = 1 / (-1j * Imstub) * Zo

lstub = symbols('l')
lstub = abs((solve(Zin - 1j * Zo * math.tan(Beta * lstub), lstub)))
xLam_Stub = (lstub / Lambda)

print('Comprimento do stub em curto (m)'), print(lstub)
print('Distância do stub à carga (m)'), print(dstub)
```

this is my code. When I run it, the graphs appear, but...
[Graph1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaoKm.png) [Graph2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEc68.png) [Graph3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qxuh.png)
Also, I received this error after closing the graphs windows
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOhic.png)

Comment: Try printing your values. You will then find that you only have a single value. d is [0]. Your tupple error comes after the plotting part.

Comment: How can I do this for the exact values?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on either mistakes in the equations or wrong initial values, none of which can be resolved through programming but a mathematical understanding of the underlying problem.